# Filling in NaN columns if another column is not NaN w/ string concatenation

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to concatenate two columns together if they are not NaN, like so:

```
if(df[pd.notnull([df["Col1"]])] and df[pd.notnull([df["Col2"]])]):
    df["Col3"] = df["Col1"] + df["Col2"]
```

If both of these columns are not NULL/NaN, put the other two strings together and put that into column 3.

How might I go about doing this?
pd.notnull does not behave how I would expect it to.

I am hoping for it to behave like this:

```
"First Name" "Last Name" "Full Name"
 a            b           a b
 a1           b1          a1 b1
 a2           b2          a2 b2
```

Where, before formatting it would have NaN in the "Full Name" Column.

This is how the data would look before formatting:

```
"First Name" "Last Name" "Full Name" 
a            b            NaN
a1           b1           NaN
a2           b2           NaN
NaN          NaN          a3 b3
```

Comment: I tried to implement logic from those posts to no avail- so I figured I'd ask a more general combinatorics question.

Comment: @Sam See updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46244516/4909087).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.loc` to set `Col3` like

```
In [383]: df
Out[383]:
  Col1 Col2
0    a    h
1  NaN    i
2    c    j
3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN    l
5    f    m
6    g  NaN

In [384]: df.loc[df[['Col1', 'Col2']].notnull().all(1), 'Col3'] = df.Col1 + df.Col2

In [385]: df
Out[385]:
  Col1 Col2 Col3
0    a    h   ah
1  NaN    i  NaN
2    c    j   cj
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN    l  NaN
5    f    m   fm
6    g  NaN  NaN
```

Details

```
In [386]: df[['Col1', 'Col2']].notnull().all(1)
Out[386]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Great answer!  OOV

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Full Name'].fillna(df['First Name'].str.cat(df['Last Name'], sep=' '))

0      a b
1    a1 b1
2    a2 b2
3    a3 b3
Name: Full Name, dtype: objec
```

**In place with `pd.DataFrame.update`**

```
df.update(
    df['Full Name'].fillna(df['First Name'].str.cat(df['Last Name'], sep=' ')
)

df

  First Name Last Name Full Name
0          a         b       a b
1         a1        b1     a1 b1
2         a2        b2     a2 b2
3        NaN       NaN     a3 b3
```

---

**Make a copy**

```
df.assign(**{
    'Full Name':
        df['Full Name'].fillna(df['First Name'].str.cat(df['Last Name'], sep=' '))
})

  First Name Last Name Full Name
0          a         b       a b
1         a1        b1     a1 b1
2         a2        b2     a2 b2
3        NaN       NaN     a3 b3
```